# Exact value of parameter to produce closed curve and 2 singular points

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

For D somewhere between -11 and -12 (I think!), the following function produces a graph with a closed curve and two singular points.

$$
y^4-4y^2=-x^4+3x^3+3x^2+Dx-3
$$

I plotted a 2D [graph](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzNrpA9zKRk), animated for various values of D. The two singular point can be thought of as local peaks in the 3D space (x, y, D).

What is the exact value of D when this occurs?

Comment: What makes you think so? Is there more information?

Comment: I've added a link to a graph that indicates there are two local peaks.

Comment: Sorry for the typo - it is -3, (not +3) for the constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After correction of the typo, the singular points are shown on the joints graphs.

Figure 3 shows the case of isolated singular points.[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TonyK If you look at when I gave this comment, the answer consisted of a single line with no mathematical content. Please consider the historical context of a post - you have the ability to read the history of an edited post by clicking on the 'edited xx mins ago' link.

Comment: @TonyK: All the mess comes from the correction of a typo by jamesthenabignumber. My first answer wasn't up to date, so I partly delete it. Then, Daniel had right to say that the remaining of my previous post was not informative. It tooks more time than expected to rewrite my new answer. All's well which ends well.

Comment: That seems likely from the edit history. Just as a pointer for the future, if the system sees an answer with very little written in it, and/or someone flags an answer for low quality, it gets put into the review queue where other users vote on if they think the post is indeed low quality. For that reason you might want to instead edit with a disclaimer that you are attempting to fix the mistake/typo you made.

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work JJacquelin, and I am very sorry for the typo in the original formulation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathematica, I obtained the approximate value $$D \approx -11.960949537899285187548631685245893662483813189418\ldots.$$  This is a root of the quartic polynomial $$27 z^4+270 z^3-3591 z^2+2898 z+457807.$$  This value corresponds to a curve that self-intersects at $y = \pm \sqrt{2}$ and $x \approx 1.081941108085261568294448553915$.  But if you want the value of $D$ for which there are two **isolated** points, what you want is a different root of the same quartic above:  $$D \approx -13.658381026615799846061572151507704638149295780586\ldots.$$

However, there is a difference in the equation you stated, and the equation given in the video link.  Yours says $+3$ whereas the video says $-3$.  If we go by the video, then the desired values of $D$ correspond to the real roots of the quartic $$27 z^4+270 z^3-675 z^2-3042 z+9751.$$  These are approximately $$\begin{align*} D &\approx  -11.072841028502857454702305258829734721106264530500\ldots, \\ D &\approx 
-4.0881318682078769707577137157340189215903558111322\ldots, \end{align*}$$  the first of which is the situation with two isolated points.  The coordinates of these points are approximately $(x,y) = (2.3934900075826234528, \pm \sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I did mean -3, rather than +3.